Why do I keep getting an unrecognized data type when running the fit method in this CNN code using Keras 3 API?
I am following an online course and running the following code in python 3.11 to build a CNN for image classification using Keras 3.6 and TensorFlow 2.18:
# Convolutional Nueral Network

import tensorflow as tf
import keras as kr

from tf_keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import numpy as np
from tf_keras.preprocessing import image

print(tf.__version__)
print(kr.__version__)

# Part 1 - Data Preprocessing

#   Preprocessing the Training Set

#       Below, an instance of the class of ImageDataGenerator that causes transformations 
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(    
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset/training_set",
    target_size=(64,64),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

#   Preprocessing the Test Set

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "dataset/test_set",
    target_size=(64,64),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

# Part 2 - Buildinging the CNN 

#   Initializing the CNN

cnn = kr.Sequential()

#   Step 1 - Convolution

cnn.add(kr.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, 
                         kernel_size=3,
                         activation='relu', 
                         input_shape=[64,64,3]))

#   Step 2 - Pooling

cnn.add(kr.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2,
                            strides=2,
                            padding='valid'))

#   Step 3 - Adding a second convolutional layer

cnn.add(kr.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, 
                         kernel_size=3,
                         activation='relu'))


#   Step 4 - Adding a second pooling layer

cnn.add(kr.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2,
                            strides=2,
                            padding='valid'))

#   Step 5 Flattening

cnn.add(kr.layers.Flatten())

#   Step 6 Full Connection

cnn.add(kr.layers.Dense(units=128, 
                        activation='relu'))

#   Step 7 Output Layer

cnn.add(kr.layers.Dense(units=1, 
                        activation='sigmoid')) #Sigmoid b/c classification is binary

# Part 3 - Training the CNN

#   Step 1 Compiling the CNN

cnn.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
            metrics= ['accuracy'])

#   Step 2 Training the CNN on the Training Set and Evaluating it on the Test Set

cnn.fit(x = training_set,
        validation_data = test_set,
        epochs=25)

When it gets to Part 3, Step 2 Training the CNN, and the cnn.fit method line runs, I get the following error:
  raise ValueError(f"Unrecognized data type: x={x} (of type {type(x)})")

ValueError: Unrecognized data type: x=<tf_keras.src.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x141d69210> (of type <class 'tf_keras.src.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>)

How do I fix this? I looked at the Keras 3 documentation and it shows that only certain datatypes are allowed (https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/), but I'm not sure how to convert my training_set and test_set to those types.
I tried converting the training_set and test_set to a numpy array during the fitting using
cnn.fit(x = np.array(training_set),
        validation_data = np.array(test_set),
        epochs=25)

but that seems to run for a long time and use up a lot of RAM. I am not sure what else to try. I appreciate the help!

As you are using generators, try cnn.fit_generator( training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=25)

keras 3 is not compatible with tf.keras, you should not be mixing those libraries as they are not the same library at all.

I have reviewed your code and made some changes. I imported tf_keras and used
tf_keras instead of keras in the code, and it works. Please refer to the gist
for your reference.
